# How does google chrome detect when other windows are maximized on top of it?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, video-capture, obs-studio, google-meet

I've been recording google meet conference calls with OBS since they made this a premium feature on the site. So far it's all been going well except when I have to maximize a different window on top of it, then the video feed and screen share goes blank and everything else freezes. Just having another window on top doesn't seem to cause this behavior, only when it is explicitly maximized. Tried to do it on firefox and it seems to work just fine, so I'm guessing its a google chrome thing. I can't change the browser though due to audio limitations (I have a virtual cable set up for chrome so I don't pick up random audio from firefox and other programs) and also because it's the one in which google meet behaves the best, so I was wondering if there was a way to block the specific element or whatever it is that chrome uses to detect other windows being maximized on top of it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess it's not the maximise status, it's the complete hiding of the video window.

If you can't see any of the window, it is no longer rendered at all, meaning there is nothing for OBS to see. If the video is only partly covered, the entire window will still be rendered. This is a fairly standard compositing/culling method.
I'd call it a no-fix.

Comment: I've tested this a lot and it's definitely only caused by the maximization of other windows on top of google chrome. And it only happens on chromium browsers too. My question isn't just how to 'fix' this, but mainly to understand the cause of this behavior.